# Sometimes returning errors when looking for block transactions

Tags: operation

tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/BMGi65PWTKoUbcs5hVm83LciAznJSQsKTrRLZ7HiLBNnoxgsJAs/operations
result: Did not find service: GET http://localhost:8732/describe/chains/main/blocks/BMGi65PWTKoUbcs5hVm83LciAznJSQsKTrRLZ7HiLBNnoxgsJAs/operations?recurse=no

tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/BL9e4iELvy2zWqad3r2NAHdPHCjKJqueH6fbPh5iTkMYLUHUrWD/operations
Have normal results returned

Why is the operations interface sometimes reporting an error?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason would be that your node did not already receive the block `BMGi65PWTKoUbcs5hVm83LciAznJSQsKTrRLZ7HiLBNnoxgsJAs`.

Is your node bootstrapped ?
You can see your current chain head with the following rpc:

```
tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/header
```

Also, the operations rpc call does not work for pruned blocks (blocks older than the current checkpoint), that should be fixed soon.
But that is not your issue since `BL9e4iELvy...` is older than `BMGi65PW...`.
See this ticket for more details: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/562

Comment: tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/header 
How to see if bootstrapped  "protocol": "Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd",
  "chain_id": "NetXdQprcVkpaWU",
  "hash": "BMUDtjN6BKdXgyGrvFUFUs4FzCwmjY8YpAjsMqbGGKGCn8pkpBs",
  "level": 582231, "proto": 4,
  "predecessor": "BKo5mJRfHBWSE2KTd3STE67EUxJ7EjueXPMJ1hVjBLmbLpBv3bE",

Comment: Your head is at level 582231 but the block you asked for (`BMGi65PWTKo...`) is at level 583183 so your node did not already receive it, you need to wait 952 blocks.

The 'bootstrapped' rpc is explained here: https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/api/rpc.html#get-monitor-bootstrapped.

Please next time surround the code with backticks in order to make it more 'human readable'. See https://tezos.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code for more information about formatting text.

Comment: My other node is synced to the latest, and this problem is also there.
Do you know why?I saw the recent checkpoint is 565249.
I am running full mode.

Comment: Is the rpc call `tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/BMGi65PWTKoUbcs5hVm83LciAznJSQsKTrRLZ7HiLBNnoxgsJAs/header` working ?
If your node is bootstrapped, your checkpoint is at level L where L is less than `583183` and the rpc call `tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/BMGi65PWTKoUbcs5hVm83LciAznJSQsKTrRLZ7HiLBNnoxgsJAs/operations` to the bootstrapped node does not work, then it is an issue. Please open a ticket on https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/ describing the problem so it can be reproduced and fixed.